# Displaying Data in a tabular form in django admin

Tags: python, django

I have a draft model  name Course.

```
class Course(models.Model):
courseId = models.CharField(unique=True, primary_key=True, max_length=6)
courseName = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=25)

def __str__(self):
    return (self.courseName + ' ' + self.courseId).upper()
```

Then registered it in django admin. I need help on how to display the course name and courseId in a tabular form.

Answer (score 1):

In `admin.py`:

```
class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('courseId', 'courseName')

admin.site.register(Course, CourseAdmin)
```

Read [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) for more.